# Fetch data from db using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO, I'm using it as advised by senior users in this website.
I'm trying to get data from my table using pdo, using while, so I can get all the data "organized".

My query is working, but for some reason I can't even dump it.

Heres my code:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa FROM account.quests_faq WHERE ativa='YES' ORDER BY nivel DESC");
        while($row = $conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            if ($tipo=='main'){
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='$row['id']'"><font color="green">Nivel '$row['nivel']' - '$row['titulo']'</font></a></li><br>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='$row['id']'"><font color="red">Nivel '$row['nivel']' - '$row['titulo']'</font></a></li><br>';
            }
        }
```

So, in a resume.
I have a table with titles, some text and an id.
I want to get this data from it and echo it.

Hope you can help me, sorry for the newb doubt.

EDIT 1:

```
$username = 'sssss';
        $password = 'sssss';
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxxxxx;dbname=account', $username, $password);
            $sql = "SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa FROM account.quests_faq WHERE ativa='YES' ORDER BY nivel DESC";
            $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='.$row['id'].'"><font color="green">Nivel '.$row['nivel'].' - '.$row['titulo'].'</font></a></li><br>';
            }else{
                echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='.$row['id'].'"><font color="red">Nivel '.$row['nivel'].' - '.$row['titulo'].'</font></a></li><br>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to execute this query in a simple mysql client? Does it produce the expected result?

Comment: Yes, everything works. Theres something wrong with the while, or the way I'm query'ing it, but I don't know what...

Comment: First of all prepare your SQL query : Read More Here : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Then use foreach() insted of while() That will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, advise you were given is wrong.

Not *use* but *learn*.
You have to **learn** something before using it.
There are many tutorials on PDO around (all of them crappy ones though) but at least you can learn proper syntax from there

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa FROM account.quests_faq WHERE ativa='YES' ORDER BY nivel DESC";
    // look this string contains SQL query. so, the variable is named $sql
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    // in the next line we are getting a statement object from the function query()
    // this is why variable called $stmt
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // and now we can start iterating this statement.
    // statement, Carl. Not connection to database
    // which is called $conn, if you get an idea
```

also you have to enable error reporting for PDO.

And yes, as it was said in the other answer, your PHP syntax is also wrong. You are supposed to learn it too, instead of banging together random lines of code and then asking others to fix it for you.

Start from less complex syntax, from echoing one single variable without decoration. And ask one question per post. As for the PDO part you already got the answer

Comment: Thank you for your response but it still doesn't return a thing.
Should I be using FETCH_ASSOC in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a foreach loop. Once the loop is finished you can actually use the `$arrRows` array anywhere throughout the file! I was told by one of the senior web developers that this is a better way to do it.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $key => $arrRows){
         echo $arrRows['COLUMN_NAME_HERE'];
    }
```

Here is a demo function that will select values from a table using PDO:

```
function showPost($uID){
        global $numRecords, $dbConnection, $stmt;
        connect(); //Run connect function (../connections/connections.php)

        $sqlStr = "SELECT user_post.*, user.name, user.avatar FROM user_post JOIN user ON user_post.uID = user.uID WHERE user_post.uID = ".$uID. " ORDER BY post_time DESC";

        // Run query
        try
        {
            $stmt = $dbConnection->query($sqlStr);
            if($stmt === false)
            {
                die("Error executing the query: $sqlStr");
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $error)
        {
            // Display error message if applicable
            echo "An error occurred: ".$error->getMessage();
        }
        $numRecords = $stmt->rowcount();

        
        // Close the databaase connection
        $dbConnection = NULL;
    }
```

Let me know if you have anymore questions

Answer (score -1):

You were using your connection variable `conn` instead of your query variable `sql` to fetch your query results.

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa FROM account.quests_faq WHERE ativa='YES' ORDER BY nivel DESC");
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
if ($tipo=='main')
    echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='$row['id']'"><font color="green">Nivel '$row['nivel']' - '$row['titulo']'</font></a></li><br>';
else
    echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='$row['id']'"><font color="red">Nivel '$row['nivel']' - '$row['titulo']'</font></a></li><br>';
}
```

Or you can do similarly using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa FROM account.quests_faq WHERE ativa='YES' ORDER BY nivel DESC");
$sql->execute();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if ($tipo=='main')
        echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='$row['id']'"><font color="green">Nivel '$row['nivel']' - '$row['titulo']'</font></a></li><br>';
    else
        echo '<li><a href="index.php?s=quest_info&id='$row['id']'"><font color="red">Nivel '$row['nivel']' - '$row['titulo']'</font></a></li><br>';
}
```